# ListView doesn't show until I click on the SearchView

Tags: java, android

my ListView shows up only after I click/activate the SearchView, I suppose it refreshes the view on some way and shows the listview.

I have tried refreshing (rebuilding) the view and the listview.

Here's my listview:

```
sviEventiListView = this.findViewById(R.id.ListListaEvenata);

        sviEventiListView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return eventiList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventistavka, null);
                }
                final Eventi row = eventiList.get(position);
                TextView eventiName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.EventNaziv);
                eventiName.setText(row.getNaziv());
                TextView eventiDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.OpisEventa);
                eventiDesc.setText(row.getOpis());



                return convertView;
            }

        });
```

It runs after this part of the code (getting the data from the database, which works as it should):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        AndroidNetworking.enableLogging();


AndroidNetworking.get(Config.url+"api/Eventi").build().getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            Log.d("Response:", response.getString(0));

            JSONArray array = response;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject myData = array.getJSONObject(i);
                JsonObject element = gson.fromJson(myData.toString(), JsonObject.class);
                Eventi eventi = gson.fromJson(element, Eventi.class);

                eventiList.add(eventi);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < eventiList.size(); i++) {
            Log.wtf("TEST2", "onResponse: " + eventiList.get(i).getNaziv());
            Log.wtf("TEST2", "onResponse: " + eventiList.get(i).getOpis());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ANError anError) {

    }

});
```

Here is my layout file as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainPageActivity"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >


    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/PretragaBarId"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:queryHint="Pretraga"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noItems"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/noResult"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListListaEvenata"
        android:layout_below="@id/PretragaBarId"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Expected result is showing the Empty search bar on the top, and the list with 3 members instantly after running the app, but it only shows up after I click on the SearchView.

[Before clicking on the searchview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTB5H.png)

[After clicking on the searchview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw5zj.png)

And yes it does stay after closing the searchview, I haven't assigned the listview to it.

Here are my declarations:

```
public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView sviEventiListView;
    private BaseAdapter adapter;
    //private int myLastVisiblePos;
    TextView noItemsTextView;
    private ProgressBar mainProgressBar;
    private List<Eventi> eventiList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Comment: Do you use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to your adapter after receiving the data?

Comment: Please , add the codes for the search view , it looks like the problem in the codes not in xml , the search view codes is changing a variable from null to something else when you click it that why it shows up

Comment: I have added a call of `private void NotifyDataChange() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`
but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @AmerAnajjem There is not code for the search view, it doesn't do anything at the moment, except visually being there (xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

The only thing required was to add:

`sviEventiListView.requestLayout();`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see which method gets executed after loading the data into your list, but I think you need to use:

```java
  BaseAdapter myAdapter =new BaseAdapter;
  myAdapter...//configure it
  sviEventiListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
   myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//call this after loading data into list view
```

Because of this reason you should declare a adapter object first.

Comment: I have added a call of `private void NotifyDataChange() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`
but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry it seems like I'm blind, I can't see it.

Comment: No you are not blind, I have just added it now, but I have tried it before and it didn't work, so I deleted it, now I readded it, but no luck.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did.

Comment: You should use a ListAdapter, maybe this is working better.

Comment: For some reason the size of my

`private ArrayList<Eventi> eventiList= new ArrayList<>();`

becomes 0, after it leaves the onResponse method. On the end of the onResponse method, it's size is 2 (3 items), I have only 1 instance of this list.

Comment: In your post I can't see where you declare the object, so I don't know what exactly happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the array is not saving your actual data, it is saving the references to them. So as soon as onResponse is over the original JSON objects will be destroyed and the array which is pointing to them becomes 0. Can you try to copy or `clone()` the data before adding to the list?

Comment: So sorry, I wanted to add this as comment but I'm using the stack exchange app and made a mistake. Will delete this tomorrow... Sorry about that.